# Create a new jpg file when user hits the route- Flask-Ajax

Tags: python, ajax, flask

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/' , methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    print("hello")
    if request.method == 'GET':
        text = request.args.get("image")
        

        print(text)

        base64_img_bytes = text.encode('utf-8')
        with open('decoded_image.jpeg', 'wb') as file_to_save:
            decoded_image_data = base64.decodebytes(base64_img_bytes)
            file_to_save.write(decoded_image_data)
```

The above code is my app.py in which an ajax request is sent to the route with an image captured from the camera of the user. I encode the image and write that encoded text into an image, but this is for one user I want to achieve this for multiple users. how can I achieve this for every user?

Every time a user hits route, create a new jpg file and save it local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Every time a user hits route, create a new jpg file and save it local.

You need to generate new filename each time, this can be done for example using [`uuid`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) following way, add following import

```
import uuid
```

and replace

```
with open('decoded_image.jpeg', 'wb') as file_to_save:
```

using

```
with open('decoded_image_{}.jpeg'.format(uuid.uuid4().hex), 'wb') as file_to_save:
```